# simple rookie regex help needed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

i have a simple regex expression below to pull out the value within a string that is surrounded by end**end, example below.  However, although it's stupidly simple im struggling to get the results I need!  Is there something obvious I'm missing!
Many thanks as always.

```
var str = "endhelloend";
var match = Regex.Match(str, @"end([a-z]+)end$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if(match.Success)
{
    result = match.Groups[0].Value  // should return 'hello'
}
```

Comment: Your regex says that only letters can be between end and end. Is that the case? Can you provide sample cases where it should and should not match?

Comment: Do you want to extract text content from the HTML files,Is that you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **solution 1** to extract .html text content and then filter your desired text from text by using **solution 2**.

1. **To clean html elements within .htm file, try this:**

   ```
   string CleanXml(string DirtyXml)
   {
       //string clean = ""; 
       int startloc = 0, endloc = 0;

       for (int x = 0; x <= DirtyXml.Length-1; x++)
       {
           if (DirtyXml[x] == '<')
           {
               startloc = x;
               x++;
           }
           if (DirtyXml[x] == '>')
           {
               endloc = x;
               x++;
               DirtyXml = DirtyXml.Remove(startloc, (endloc - startloc)+1);
               x = 0;
           }   
       }
       return DirtyXml;
   }
   ```
2. **Regex to filter text "endhelloend" to obtain "hello"**
   [image]

   ```
       string result = "";
       var str = "endhelloend";
       var match = Regex.Match(str, @"end([a-z]+)end$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
       if(match.Success)
       {
           result = match.Groups[1].Value;  // Returns 'hello'
       }
       Console.WriteLine(result);
       Console.ReadLine();
   ```

Comment: var str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"test.htm");

            var match = Regex.Match(str, @"end([a-z]+)end$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                var result = match.Groups[1].Value;  // Returns 'hello'
            }

Comment: contents of str is "<html>
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
<style>
p { color: Red; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
endhelloend
<p>This is an example</p>
</body>
</html>"

Comment: What are the contents of "test.htm"?

Comment: Provide a large sample upto three lines from "test.htm" so I could propose a solution.

Comment: I have provided the entire test.htm in the previous comment.

Comment: full example here: var str = @"<html>
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
<style>
p { color: Red; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
endhelloend
<p>This is an example</p>
</body>
</html>";


            var match = Regex.Match(str, @"end([a-z]+)end$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                var css = match.Groups[1].Value;
            }

Comment: In the htm file there is NO "end([a-z]+)end$" to match thats why regex fails.Also check my comment on your question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8267/discussion-between-owais-qureshi-and-james-radford)

Comment: "endhelloend" is the example string which is in the html that is being checked, although the test is failing..(?)

Answer (score 4):

Your pattern correctly contains the group you want to extract. A regular expression match will contain a collection of groups for you to access. In your example, try the following:

```
var str = "endhelloend";
var match = Regex.Match(str, @"end([a-z]+)end$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if(match.Success)
{
    var hello = match.Groups[1];
}
```

match.Groups[0] will return the entire match "endhelloend" so you just want the 1st group within the match.

Answer (score 3):

match.Groups[0] will match the whole regex - look at match.Groups[1].

Comment: thanks but whilst debugging matchin.Success evaluates to false so the match.group never gets hit with the example shown

Comment: You should put that information in the question. Try [a-z]+? as your matching group, see if that helps. The + is a greedy operator by default iirc, so it might be matching end, thus not finding the closing string.

Comment: Making the `+` non-greedy shouldn't have any effect.  It's true the greedy `[a-z]+` will *initially* consume the second `end`, but then it will back off far enough to let the rest of the regex ( `end$` ) match what it needs to.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this line should look like this:
`result = match.Groups[1].Value;`

Answer (score 1):

I see you're struggling with this so I will offer a little insight.

This regex `end([a-z]+)end$` will match this string "`endhelloend`".
The inner text will be in capture group 1.
It will not match the same string when its a substring like this
"`endhelloend of the world`".

The reason is you have an end of string metachar (assertion) `$` as part of the regex
just after 'end'.

So you could just take out `$` in the regex and it should work fine.
There are other things to take into account though. I'll comment it in you're regex.

```
end        // find a literal 'end'
(          // Capture group 1 open
  [a-z]+   // Find as many characters a-z as possible (including 'e' 'n' 'd' ins sequence
)          // Capture group 1 close
end        // find a literal 'end'
$          // End of string assertion (the last 'end' must be the last word in the string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will give you any alphabetic character that's between the word **end**, but won't capture the actual word *end*

```
(?<=end)[a-z]+?(?=end)
```

Comment: Lookarounds add needless complexity without bringing any benefit.  Your regex will work, but it's because you left the `$` off (as @sln explained), not because of the lookarounds.

Comment: @Alan Moore, I actually left out the **$** (un)intentionally  :D, the question used the string *endhelloend* as test, not *endhelloend 123 455...*  What sort of complexity would the lookaround introduce?  I didn't think its performance hit would be so big, and imho this is prettier `match.Value`